# How can I initialize my form Image and Integer fields with model data?

Tags: django

I've managed to initialize a CharField, but how can I do the same with ImageField and IntegerField?
My forms.py:

```
class GoodGet(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Good_Get
        Size = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Good.objects.all())
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, good_id1=None, **kwargs):
        super(forms.ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if good_id1 is not None:
            obj = Good.objects.filter(id = good_id1)
            self.fields['Name'].initial = Good.objects.get(id=good_id1)
            self.fields['Photo'].initial = Good.objects.get(id=good_id1)
            self.fields['Price'].initial = Good.objects.get(id=good_id1)
            for good in obj:
                good_sizes = good.Size.all()
            self.fields['Size'].queryset = good_sizes
```

So, I need to write these strings correctly:

```
            self.fields['Photo'].initial = Good.objects.get(id=good_id1)
            self.fields['Price'].initial = Good.objects.get(id=good_id1)
```

How?
Good model:

```
class Good(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    Type = models.ForeignKey('Type', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Available = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    Photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'clothes_photos')
    Price = models.IntegerField(default = '0')
    Discount = models.IntegerField(default = '0')
    Size = models.ManyToManyField('Size')
```

Comment: can you show `Good` model?

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off initialising this in the view.

```
good = Good.objects.filter(id = good_id1)
form = GoodGet(instance=good)
```